# How do you separate values from an array into their own individual values or variables in Azure Logic App

Tags: arrays, azure, azure-logic-apps, dataverse

Need your assistance here. I am trying to separate values from an array in an Azure Logic App I am developing.

I took some data from a dataverse table, and then took only the data from one column using the "Select" step. So the output is an array of data from that one column.

Now, all I wanted to do is put those values from the array into each of their own value or variables. So I need the step or expression to be able to achieve it.

Thanks for the help in advance!

I tried to use several steps. However, I am getting failure notifications.

Comment: We have an action "filter array" in Azure logic app. you can use it with required filter expression. 
Could you please add input and output sample data?

Comment: Here is a sample output I got when I used the "Select" Data Operation step to get the data on one specific column:

[
  "testuser.2@contoso.com",
  "testuser.5@contoso.com",
  "testuser.1@contoso.com",
  "testuser.7@contoso.com",
  "testuser.8@contoso.com",
  "testuser,4@contoso.com",
  "testuser.3@contoso.com",
  "testuser.6@contoso.com"
]

Now, what I need to do next is to separate the values from the array into their own objects/variables. Can you advise?

Comment: if we you want to use them for some process/operation, you can run a For each loop on data/mailid list and use 'item()' as expression in dynamic content to fetch current mailid.

Answer (score 0):

> All I wanted to do is put those values from the array into each of their own value or variables. So I need the step or expression to be able to achieve it.

*You can do this in the following way-*

Here I am taking inputs from an excel which is having single column like below

[image]

**Workflow**

[image]

Even I am getting the same output in **Select** operation alike you

[image]

This is how, I am separating each values from the above array

[image]

I am selecting these inputs from **dynamic content** wherein `Output: body('Select')` and `Current item: items('For_each')`

[image]

***Getting output as below-***

[image]

In this way, you can fetch each values from an array.